# linq to xml with namespace prefix

Tags: xml, linq, namespaces, prefix

I have the following xml

```
<Location xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Latitude>-1</Latitude>
<Longtitude>-1</Longtitude>
</Location>
```

And without the namespace (xmlns:i...), I could use the following the query

```
//xdoc is an XDocument loaded with the above xml
var locCollection = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Location")
```

with namespace but without the prefix "i", I could use the following the query

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
var locCollection = from p in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Location")
```

So how do I deal with te "i" prefix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you provide the namespace prefix, you need to explicitly prefix the XML elements that are in that namespace. So in your example, if you explicitly specify the prefix as in `i:Location` then your queries will work.

```
<i:Location xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <Latitude>-1</Latitude> 
  <Longtitude>-1</Longtitude> 
</i:Location>
```

The reason it worked without the prefix is because with out the prefix specified the namespace is considered the default namespace therefore `Location` was by default scoped to the namespace.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This actually works. But the xml you saw was a response I got from the WCF service. I used something like [DataContract(Namespace="")] public class Location{}, which by default doesn't specify the prefix (i:location). I know that's a totally different question, but do you happen to know the solution?

Comment: You will need to provide a little more context, maybe if you post another question with the sample that reproduces the problem.